# The type 'FileMode' exists in both MonoGame.Framework and 'mscorlib'

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm working on moving my XNA game to MonoGame. I have finally reached an issue with System.IO.FileMode and System.IO.FileAccess. Both of these are in both mscorlib and monogame.framework. I have tried the following and none of them work. I'm using VS 2015 if that matters.

```
global::System.IO.FileMode.Open // still gives the same error

using io = gloabal::System.IO;
io.FileMode.Open // still gives teh same error.
```

Any one know a work around for this issue with monogame?

Comment: If you use `System.IO.FileMode.Open` you **can not** go wrong. Something else must be causing the issue.

Comment: Tried that as well. Seems like monogame 3.5 which is not officially out yet fixes this error.

https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/pull/4039

Comment: The newest code didn't fix it. So I am now back to trying to figure out what to do.

Comment: how did you solve the problem..? @crzyone9584

Comment: @rahulroy9202 I never fixed it. I stopped using monogame and went to SFML. Although its been a while so this may actually be fixed now by a new version.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, my mistake came from a bad reference of MonoGame.Framework.dll. I was using the one in Windows8 folder, instead of the one located in the Windows folder (which does not contains any System.IO reference).

Comment: Having the same problem now.  How can you tell which folder the dll is contained in from the reference manager?

Comment: Select Monogame.Framework in the reference , Look at the path in properties window (if it contains Windows8).

Comment: This fixed it for me-- I'm not sure what happened; but, I was using the Nez (https://github.com/prime31/Nez) library, which depends on the OpenGL one. Somehow it picked up the Windows8 as the library it wanted when I first tried to build it.

Comment: This happened to me after upgrading Visual Studio from 2015 to 2017 RC. I solved it by fiddling with the references. Now that I understand it I *think* reinstalling MonoGame might help.